# Date to localeString with milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, date

In Javascript I'm trying to convert a Date object to a locale string, with the `toLocaleString()` function. What I want is the converted locale string with milliseconds. Is that possible?

```js
const time = "2018-12-03T16:24:05.150Z";
const date = new Date(time);
const str = date.toLocaleString();

console.log(date.toLocaleString()); //3-12-2018 17:24:05
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have already tried.

Comment: Added the code to the question

Comment: you need to use a library like moment.js

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet, as with `toLocaleString()` it's always important to consider that each user's output will be different. That said, I don't think this really changes your question all that much.

Comment: @theapologist I want a locale string with milliseconds. Not to convert a date to milliseconds.

Comment: Should format the string yourself using the various Date methods. `toLocaleString()` produces different formats in different locales. Or use a date library

Comment: @PsykoSoldi3r sorry, misunderstood your question.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `toLocaleString()`, as there is no native `option` for it, nor is the output consistent enough across locales to simply concatenate the milliseconds. For example, my output ends in `AM`, whereas yours ends in the time of day.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible but you’ll have to construct the string using an options argument, format the parts and add them yourself.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) and many others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the key is `fractionalSecondDigits`

```
let iso_str = '2022-06-11T01:51:59.618Z';
let d = new Date(iso_str);

let tz = 'America/Santiago'
let options = {
    timeZone:tz ,
    timeZoneName:'longOffset',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
    fractionalSecondDigits: 3
}


str_locale = d.toLocaleString("sv-SE",options);
//output: 2022-06-10 21:51:59,618 GMT−04:00
iso_str_tz = str_locale.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s+(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}),(\d+)\s+/,'$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6.$7').replace('GMT−', '-' ).replace('GMT+','+')
//output: 2022-06-10T21:51:59.618-04:00


console.log('iso_str               : ',iso_str);
console.log('str_locale            : ',str_locale);
console.log('iso_str_tz            : ',iso_str_tz);
console.log('iso_str_tz --> date   : ',new Date(iso_str_tz));
console.log('iso_str_tz --> iso_str: ',new Date(iso_str_tz).toISOString());
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using **date.getMilliseconds()** ?

```js
const time = "2018-12-03T16:24:05.150Z";
const date = new Date(time);
const str = date.toLocaleString();

console.log(date.toLocaleString() + " " + date.getMilliseconds()); 
//3-12-2018 17:24:05 ???
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const time = "2018-12-03T16:24:05.150Z";
const date = new Date(time);
const str = date.toLocaleString();
const result = new Date(str).getTime();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned a keyword for milliseconds is missing.
I built a javascript clock for practise and run into the same problem but I already built an interface for `toLocaleString` so I decide to add my own feature that probably won't work with all languages but it's good enough.
I choose **millisecond** as keyword. I think as format information a combination of using **n-digit** like `2-digit` and **anything** for no specific millisecond format (cause also include `numeric`) would be enough.
As connection I use **colon** when the format of `hourCycle` is defined as `h23` or `h24` and **space** else.
(Code in snippet without error handling, trigger is onchange so fill in *en* and than change hourCycle to *h11*)

```js
function toLocalStringFromDate(nDate, nLanguage, nOptions){
    if("millisecond" in nOptions){ // own keyword option
        if(nOptions.millisecond.endsWith("-digit")){
            let tDigits = parseInt(nOptions.millisecond.substring(0, nOptions.millisecond.length-6));
            // extract amount of digits from format
            let tLength = (""+nDate.getMilliseconds()).length;
            // length of current milliseconds
            return nDate.toLocaleString(nLanguage, nOptions)
                // basic formatting
                +("hourCycle" in nOptions && (nOptions.hourCycle == "h23" || nOptions.hourCycle == "h24") ? ':' : ' ')
                // separator
                +("0".repeat(tDigits)+nDate.getMilliseconds()).substring(tLength, tDigits+tLength);
                // n-digit of zeros followed by milliseconds shifted by n digit is substring(tDigits+tLength-tDigits, tDigits+tLength);
        }
        else{
            return nDate.toLocaleString(nLanguage, nOptions)+("hourCycle" in nOptions && (nOptions.hourCycle == "h23" || nOptions.hourCycle == "h24") ? ':' : ' ')+nDate.getMilliseconds();
        }
    }
    else{
        return nDate.toLocaleString(nLanguage, nOptions);
    }
}

window.document.body.children[1].lastElementChild.value = "{\"hourCycle\": \"h23\", \"millisecond\": \"3-digit\"}";
```

```css
input{width: 60%;}
```

```html
<p><b>Language: </b><input onchange="console.log(toLocalStringFromDate(new Date(), this.value, JSON.parse(this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.lastElementChild.value)));"></p>
<p><b>Options: </b><input onchange="console.log(toLocalStringFromDate(new Date(), this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.lastElementChild.value, JSON.parse(this.value)));"></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this with the following lines of code

```js
const date = new Date();
const localDateTime = date.toLocaleString();
const currentDateObj = new Date(localDateTime); 
const convertLocalDateTimeToMS = currentDateObj.getTime(); 
console.log(convertLocalDateTimeToMS); // 1630060060000
```

Comment: `currentDateObj` is an invalid date. Locale strings cannot always be parsed back to a Date object.

Comment: Can you show me where it is showing as an invalid date.

Comment: Sure, running your 3 first lines in France makes `currentDateObj` an invalide date, thus making your snippet show `NaN`. The value of `localDateTime` is "27/08/2021, 18:23:11".